# Open browser with URL after wamp server loads

Tags: wampserver

I'm looking to be able to start Wamp Server and after it loads apache and mysql have chrome automatically open up with a url of the local server.

So essentially all that a person would need to do is to click on the wamp server icon and my localwebsite loads up in a browser automatically.

Is this possible?

I was looking at the wampmanager.ini file and trying some lines under

```
;WAMPSTARTUPACTIONSTART
Action: run; FileName: "D:/Programs/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.12/php-win.exe";Parameters: "refresh.php";WorkingDir: "D:/Programs/wamp/scripts"; Flags: waituntilterminated
Action: resetservices
Action: readconfig;
Action: service; Service: wampapache; ServiceAction: startresume; Flags: ignoreerrors
Action: service; Service: wampmysqld; ServiceAction: startresume; Flags: ignoreerrors
;WAMPSTARTUPACTIONEND
```

But i get errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, thats an interesting idea.

The problem you are having is that you should not edit the `wampmanager.ini` file, as this is rebuilt from `wampmanager.tpl` each time you start WAMPManager or do a `right click -> refresh` on the wampmanager icon, the Green `W` icon.

So edit `\wamp\wampmanager.tpl`

Change this section from this original state ( **back it up first** )

```
[StartupAction]
;WAMPSTARTUPACTIONSTART
Action: run; FileName: "${c_phpCli}";Parameters: "refresh.php";WorkingDir: "${c_installDir}/scripts"; Flags: waituntilterminated
Action: resetservices
Action: readconfig;
Action: service; Service: wampapache; ServiceAction: startresume; Flags: ignoreerrors
Action: service; Service: wampmysqld; ServiceAction: startresume; Flags: ignoreerrors
;WAMPSTARTUPACTIONEND
```

to this

```
[StartupAction]
;WAMPSTARTUPACTIONSTART
Action: run; FileName: "${c_phpCli}";Parameters: "refresh.php";WorkingDir: "${c_installDir}/scripts"; Flags: waituntilterminated
Action: resetservices
Action: readconfig;
Action: service; Service: wampapache; ServiceAction: startresume; Flags: ignoreerrors
Action: service; Service: wampmysqld; ServiceAction: startresume; Flags: ignoreerrors
Action: run; FileName: "${c_navigator}"; Parameters: "http://localhost/phpmyadmin/"; Flags: ignoreerrors
;WAMPSTARTUPACTIONEND
```

Change the `Parameters: "http://localhost/phpmyadmin/";` to the url of the site you want to auto load. I just used phpmyadmin as a example.